# How to change width and height using a a textbox and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, textbox

I would like to give the user the chance to change the width and height using a textbox and JavaScript

This is how the HTML looks like and the code below
[image: Width and Height textboxes will allow the users the change the card size]

Here is the code

```js
let cardWidthInput = document.getElementById("card-width").value;
let cardHeightInput = document.getElementById("card-height").value;

document.getElementById("card").style.width = cardWidthInput;
document.getElementById("card").style.width = cardHeightInput;
```

```css
.card {
  height: 450px;
  width: 300px;
  }
```

```html
  <body>
    <!-- Card Properties -->
    <div class="propiedades">
      <!-- New Card Button -->
      <div class="btn-nueva-carta">
        <button type="button" id="newCard" onclick="newCard()">
          Nueva Carta
        </button>
      </div>

      <!-- Card size input boxes -->
      <div class="inputs">
        <!-- Card Width -->
        <div class="card-width">
          <label for="card-width">width: </label>
          <input type="text" id="card-width" name="card-width" />
        </div>

        <!-- Card height -->
        <div class="card-height">
          <label for="card-height">height: </label>
          <input type="text" id="card-height" name="card-height" />
        </div>

        <!-- Submit button from size controllers -->
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="bntSubmit" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Game card -->
    <div class="card">
      <div class="figura"></div>
      <div class="valor"></div>
      <div class="figura invertida"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong and how to solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript code needs to be wrapped in a function that is called by the Submit button.

```html
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="bntSubmit" onclick="changeSize()" />
```

And to get an element by class you can use the `.querySelector()` function.
When setting the card's width and height, the 'px' also needs to be included:

```
function changeSize() {
  let cardWidthInput = document.getElementById("card-width").value + "px";
  let cardHeightInput = document.getElementById("card-height").value + "px";
  let card = document.querySelector(".card");
  card.style.width = cardWidthInput;
  card.style.height = cardHeightInput;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you simply want to specify the height and font size,use CSS or style attributes,e.g. in your CSS file or `<style>` tag:

```css
#textbold{
    height:200px;
    font-size:14pt;
}
```

Then in your html:

```html
<input id="textboxid"...>
```

Comment: Please [format your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/601145) so others can read it.